# Classpath: and Spring, log 4j

Tags: spring, log4j, classpath

Dear All, 
I have a problem when trying to initialize my log4j configuration from spring.

```
<bean id="log4jInitializer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="staticMethod">
        <value>org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer.initLogging</value>
    </property>
    <property name="arguments">
                      <list>
            <value>classpath:/resources/META-INF/spring/log4j.xml</value>
                            </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [/resources/META-INF/spring/log4j.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

When I try to put a breakpoint and watch the value Location of function

> public static void initLogging(java.lang.String location) throws java.io.FileNotFoundException { /* compiled code */ }

then I see that the classpath: token has not been replaced.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you very much

Comment: Is this a standalone application, or run it in a server (Tomcat,..)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> classpath:/**resources**/META-INF/spring/log4j.xml

Looks like you are using maven. But maven will "mash" the `src` and `resources` folder to one. So in case of an Maven project, the path would be: `classpath:META-INF/spring/log4j.xml`

*without slash after `classpath:`*

---

If you work on a server you should initialize the logging framework before Spring starts, because Spring itself will use it to log information while starting.

One way to do so, is to add this lines in the web.xml (than you do not need to do this in the spring configuration)

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>    
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

---

> When I try to put a breakpoint and watch the value Location of function

```
public static void initLogging(java.lang.String location) throws java.io.FileNotFoundException { /* compiled code */ }
```

Are you really sure? The magic is done in the line:
`URL url = ResourceUtils.getURL(resolvedLocation);`
So `resolvedLocation` is your string "classpath:META-INF..." but the returned URL is the "translated" path.

Pay attention to the fact, that the `getURL` function throw an exception when the ressource location starts with `classpath:` and the file is not found. So I would test what happen if I specify a not existing file. -> If no exception occurs, then there is a spelling error in `classpath:`.

Comment: It is a inside a server, and it is run probably with the xmlapplicationcontextfactory or something like that. it really looks like the "classpath:"  token is not replaced :(

Comment: @Edmondo1984: see my extended answer about the server stuff.

Comment: I am not on a classical J2EE server, I am on app server which uses spring natively. My app is deployed much later and the problem is not with that... Do you suggest to try with a file I am sure it does not exist?

Comment: @Edmondo1984: yes try a not existed file